# One to many order by with case hibernate spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a query that orders the entities by 2 dates:

```
@Query(value = "from Order order by CASE WHEN created > updated THEN created ELSE updated END desc")
```

Can I do the same with @OneToMany in the @OrderBy anotation?

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL ,mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@OrderBy(...)
private List<Dish> dishes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Also will this potentially take less time and performance compared to taking all orders and then looping over them and finding the dishes for each with a query?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate supports the @OrderBy annotation which you can add to a relationship attribute as you can see in the following code snippet.

```
@OrderBy(value = "CASE DESC")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `org.hibernate.annotations.OrderBy` instead of `javax.persistence.OrderBy`

The JavaDoc of `org.hibernate.annotations.OrderBy` claims:

> Order a collection using SQL ordering (not HQL ordering).
>
> Different from javax.persistence.OrderBy in that this expects SQL
>   fragment, JPA OrderBy expects a valid JPQL order-by fragment.

This mean:

- you can use SQL functions
- you need to use the SQL column names instead of Java field names